# which platform does not support "socket.getpeername"-python

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to use getpeername() to get peer port. In my setup ubuntu 16.04 it works well.

```
peer_port = res.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()[1]
```

but from the doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername
some platform does not support. Do we know which specific platform do not support? I searched but no luck, out products can be in multiple platforms

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3525 comment in CPython implementation suggests that at least "Cray APP" doesn't have it, but this is checked by the configure script when building Python, so it may also be lacking elsewhere.

Comment: No, there is not a canonical register of which platforms do or don't support which functions, nor can there be. Someone could build a new libc variant tomorrow that doesn't support it, compile against that libc variant _with an existing OS kernel_, and you'd be in this situation. (Similarly, there are lots of different libc implementations available for Linux, so just knowing "Linux" isn't enough; a Linux that uses musl libc is different from a linux that uses GNU libc, is different from picolibc, etc etc). Either write your software to target known OSes, or to tolerate missing functions.